# retaining hover effect when there is absolute positioned div on top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div in which there is a dropdown control. Clicking the dropdown button opens up the dropdown menu. The initial problem I had was that if the container div has a very small height, the dropdown opens but results in a scrollbar. I figured out that it is not possible to have `overflow-x: scroll` and `overflow-y: visible` at the same time. This forced me to a new strategy for the dropdown. That is, to use @floating-ui (next version after Popper 2) that allows placing one element relative to the other. So, upon clicking the dropdown button, I move the dropdown menu from it's immediate parent into the document's body (so that the entire dropdown is always visible) and then attach the floating-ui. All of this works great. The only remaining problem is, the dropdown menus were initially displaying only when the user hovers over the container. But since the dropdown is moved into the document body, mouse over the dropdown doesn't create the hover effect on the container anymore. Some of the answers suggest using pointer-event to none for the absolute div so that the pointer events propagate down. However, in my case, I want the user to use the mouse to click on any of the actions within the dropdown.

So, how do I achieve the effect I want which I am summarizing below:

1. A container div which on `:hover` displays a navbar with dropdown buttons.
2. Clicking any of the dropdown buttons will open the dropdown right below that button.
3. The entire dropdown content should be visible even if the container height is smaller than the dropdown.
4. While the mouse is on the dropdown menu, the navbar should continue to display.

[image]

Comment: Adding the code of what you've tried and explaining where you run into problems says more than a 1000 words.

Comment: Seems like you would be better handling this through JavaScript using events. When mouse enters the container, add a class `show-nav`. When it leaves, remove the class. You may also need to check when mouse enters the nav to prevent it hiding. Then update your styling to only apply when the container has that class.

Comment: Thanks Rylee, I tried that but unfortunately, moving the mouse over to the dropdown area is triggering mouseleave on the container div even though physically the mouse hasn't left. I think since the dropdown is attached to the body, regardless of where it is positioned, entering into it automatically triggers leave on other elements.

Comment: There's another approach you could take. Use `setTimeout` for a short delay after leaving to trigger the code that removes the class - then when entering the nav, clear that timeout so that it never happens. you would also need an event on `mouseleave` for the nav to actually close itself.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple vanilla JS example using a timeout with a minor delay to determine whether or not to hide upon leaving.

```js
let hideTimeout = false;

document.getElementById("hover-me").onmouseenter = function(event){
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "";
}

document.getElementById("hover-me").onmouseleave = function(event){
    hideTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "none";
    }, 10)
}

document.getElementById("dropdown").onmouseenter = function(event){
    if(hideTimeout !== false){
        clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
        hideTimeout = false;
    }
}

document.getElementById("dropdown").onmouseleave = function(event){
    document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#hover-me {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  background: blue;
}

#dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow : 0 0 4px #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover-me"></div>
<div id="dropdown" style="display:none;">
  Some content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rylee. I have added a small video of the issue. The setting is more complicated than what you have provided.

Comment: @Siva I would apply the same logic that's hiding the dropdown to also hide the menu. i.e. don't hide the menu if the dropdown is open - if the dropdown is closed, hide the menu if the mouse didn't re-enter

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding onopen and onclose handlers to the dropdown and the callbacks will add/remove a class on the container which is used to keep the menubar visible while the dropdown is open.